# Search over 3 values

Tags: swift, search

I'm building a search function for my app that let's you **search for a user by name or email**. Each user has 3 fields: **Name, email, and ID**. I'm trying to find if there's a more efficient way of doing the following task: **When you type in a name or email the other 2 fields need to be obtained, assuming the data is present.**

Right now I'm organizing all the users' data that's retrieved from the database into 3 2d arrays:

```
var emailByName = [[String]]()     // ex: ["John Doe", "email@gmail.com"] 
var nameByEmail = [[String]]()     // ex: ["email@gmail.com", "John Doe"]
var IdByEmail = [[String]]()       // ex: ["email@gmail.com", "123456789"]
```

**Note there can be identical names but emails and ID's are distinct.**

When you type in "email@gmail.com", first the app looks at the `nameByEmail` to get the name of the person, then at the `IdByEmail` to get the ID. On the other hand if you type in a name, the `emailByName` array is searched, and the results are used to search the `IdByEmail` array.

I have a sense that using 3 different arrays is not very efficient. Is there a better way to achieve this triangular search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a class or a struct with these 3 properties: id, name, email. Then perform the search using a Predicate on the array. That's the easiest route to where you want to go. There is good documentation on NSPredicate, and it works on arrays, which is pretty great.

1. make a class or a protocol and then a class or struct with the 3 properties
2. put them in the array
3. construct NSPredicates to support searching by name or email

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm researching predicates right now. Do you think I should use them or the `.filter()` function?

Comment: Filter is fine too, the advantage of Predicates is that it's the same approach for arrays and databases (assuming you use CoreData). Also, I tend to use filter mostly for very simple implementations. Would be pretty trivial to work up both approaches. I admit that while I use the functional approach a fair amount, I have found it to be a nuisance in many cases.